# Saving Get-ComputerInfo into a variable

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting

Hi I'm new to PowerShell and I am trying to use Get-ComputerInfo and split the information of the data into multiple files (for example one file with all the bios content, one with OS content, and etc).

I tried doing the following

```
$var=Get-ComputerInfo
```

and I was assuming that it may work like Get-Content where it puts it into an array (it does not). I want to use that array and just filter the data into specific files (if anyone has a better suggestion please do say)

Comment: `Get-ComputerInfo` returns a `PSObject` with a set of properties that can be accessed directly, rather than an array of strings that need to be parsed. If, for example, you have done `$CI=Get-ComputerInfo`, and you want to know the Windows version, you would retrieve it with `$CI.WindowsVersion`. Try piping the output of `Get-ComputerInfo` to `Get-Member`.

Comment: Is there not an easier possible way? I rather not have to save all the properties into an array and then call each of them like that to get the info

Comment: Nvm I ended up piping $CI.PSObject.Properties into a for each and was able to get the info thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to flesh out your own comment:

**[`Get-ComputerInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo) emits a *single object*, with all the information contained in its *properties*.**

The output object is of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ComputerInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.computerinfo).

You can also use the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) to **dynamically discover the property names with `.psobject.Properties.Name`** or, using the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet, with
`Get-ComputerInfo | Get-Member -Type Properties`

Once you know the property names of interest, you can provide them either as *literals* to a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call to extract them, or - given that thematically related properties share a common *name prefix* in this case, such as `Os` for OS (operating-system) related properties, a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards); e.g.:

```bash
$info = Get-ComputerInfo

# Explicitly enumerated properties of interest.
# Save to a file as needed.
$info | Select-Object -Property OSName, CsNumberOfLogicalProcessors


# Properties selected by shared name prefix, using a wildcard expression.
# (-Property is the first positional parameter, so it can be omitted.)
$info | Select-Object Os*
```